# Translating the information from a word problem into a function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

I would like to verify that this word problem was translated into a function correctly.

> A towing company charges a flat rate of $100.97$ dollars per day plus $0.81$ dollars per mile.

I think the function can be represented as follows if $y$ is cost and $x$ is miles: 
$$
y=100.97+(0.81)x
$$

The average rate of change in dollars per mile is $0.81$. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, so long as you are using the towing company for a single day. Very nice. :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1046974)

Comment: @Stefan4024 Yes it does? The question is "*is this correct?*", and it is. Furthermore, without an answer like this, this post stagnates on the Unanswered Questions Queue.

Comment: @Stefan4024 See [this Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/unanswered-questions) and [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments) for why I asked Mike to post his comment as an answer.